# How to partition dataframes which are partitionBy and joined with other keys?

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a lot of dataframes with customer data and the history for different legal entities, simplified:

```
Val myData = spark.createDataframe(Seq(
(1, 1, “a lot of Data”, 2010-01-01-10.00.00”),
(1, 1, “a lot of Data”, 2010-01-20-10.31.00”),
(1, 1, “a lot of Data”, 2019-06-16-12.00.00”),
(2, 5, “a lot of Data”, 2010-01-01-10.00.00”),
(2,6, “a lot of Data”, 2010-01-01-10.00.00”),
(3, 7, “a lot of Data”, 2010-01-01-10.00.00”)))
.toDF(“legalentity”, “customernumber”,”anydata”,”changetimestamp”)
```

These dataframes are stored as parquet files and exposed has external hive tables. 
The change timestamp is transformed to a >valid from<, >valid to< by views, like this

```
CREATE VIEW myview 
AS SELECT 
Legalentity, customernumber, anydata,
Changetimestamp as valid_from,
Coalesce(lead(changetimestamp) over (PARTITION by legalentity, customernumber ORDER BY changetimestamp ASC), “9999-12-31-00.00.00”) as valid_to
```

(this is simplified, there are some timestamp transformations inside needed)

There are a lot of joins between the dataframes / hive tables later.
These dataframes are store this way:

```
myDf
.orderBy(col(“legalentity”), col(“customernumber”))
.write
.format(“parquet_format”)
.mode(SaveMode.Append)
.partitionBy(“legalentity”)
.save(outputpath)
```

For legal reason the data of different legal entities must be stored in different hdfs pathes, that is done by the partitionBy clause which creates a separate folder for each legal entity. 
There are small and big legal entities with huge number of customers and others with few customers.
The number of shuffle partitions is averaged over all legal entities, that fine.

Problems:

> 

1. No more Columns to partition the dataframe are possible: 
   If we want to speed up all by adding a repartition with more columns as the partitionBy clause for writing like:

```
myDf
.orderBy(col(“legalentity”), col(“customernumber”))
.repartition(col(“legalentity”), col(“customernumber”))
.write
.format(“parquet_format”)
.mode(SaveMode.Append)
.partitionBy(“legalentity”)
.save(outputpath)
```

The number of shuffel partitions is used in every legal entity folder.
That causes partitions = >legal entity< * >number of shuffle partitions<

> 

2. Too many partitions
   There are small and big dataframes / tables. All get the same number of shuffle partitions, so small dataframes has partition sizes of 3 MB or less.
   If we use different numbers of partitions for each table so that the file size gets close to 128 MB, everything is slowed down.

We get new data every day which we just append but therefor we don’t use the number of shuffle partitions, we repartition(1). 
Sometimes we have to re-load all to compress all these partitions, but our processes are not slowed down by the new daily data.

Comment: I have a doubt. Why are u executing an order by before write? Because to perform an order by the data needs to be shuffled to one spark partition which is no use as you are writing the contents in different folders. Can u clarify that ?

Comment: There are two reasons:
1. without the orderBy the repartitionBy will end up in a chaos. It will create a new partition every time the legalentity changes
2. later on hive and impala uses the order for faster access, it has a similar effect as a partitioning with these keys

Comment: 1. The partition by picks up the values from the columns that are listed and not based on sort order 2. Its parquet data. So the best you can do is after repartition you can call sortwithinpartitions to sort the data in each spark partition. This will help in impala, hive where you are querying based the sorted column values

Comment: Yes, you can orderBy and the partitionBy or
repartition, sortwithinpartitions and partitionBy 
The problem stays the same, partition and partitionBy must have the same columns otherwiese you get the number of shuffle partitions in each legalentity= folder